# Split values in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to calculate tax also get the id for each in a single dropdown like this

```
<td><select name="tax[]" class="form-control tax" id="tax_1" style="width:80px;">
                                <option value="">Tax</option>
                                <?php $s1 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from taxes");  while($s2 = mysqli_fetch_array($s1)) { 

                                $options .= "<option value='". $s2['tax_id']."_".$s2['name']."'>".$s2['name'].'-'.$s2['rate'] . "</option>"; 
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $s2['tax_id']."_".$s2['rate']; ?>"><?php echo $s2['name'].'-'.$s2['rate']; ?></option>

                                <?php
                                }  
                                ?>
                                </select></td>
```

These values i am passing to jquery for auto calculation purpose. Values will be like `id_rate (1_5)` , I have to split it and rate i should use for calculations. How to split it there.

now i am calculating it like this

```
$('body').on('change', '.quantity,.price,.discount,.tax', function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var qty = tr.find('.quantity').val();
    var price = tr.find('.price').val();
    var tax = tr.find('.tax').val();
    var dis = tr.find('.discount').val();

    var amt = (qty * price) - (qty * price * dis) / 100;

    var tax1 = (amt * (tax / 100));
    tax1 = Number((tax1).toFixed(2));
```

But i am not getting how to split

Comment: If you need `1` and `5` separately, echo them into data attributes instead.

Comment: ...or `price.split('_')`

Comment: i did not get u. I need id for storing into db and rate for auto calculations in jquery.

Comment: yes, but how to take 2nd value for calculation and store 1st value in a variable

Comment: If you're issue is with your js-code, you should remove the PHP-tag

Comment: Do it properly, and add a _custom data attribute_ to the options that holds the rate value you need for the calculation in JS. Or, separate it even more, and create a JSON object that holds the rates for the ids, and then use the option value to look up the rate in that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try split function.

```
$('body').on('change', '.quantity,.price,.discount,.tax', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("tax")){
        var taxVal= $(this).val();
        var tax_id=taxVal.split('_')[0];
        var rate=taxVal.split('_')[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but for 2nd entry calculation is getting wrong. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Splitval(obj) {
  alert("Your Value :" + $(obj).val());
  alert("Split Value :" + $(obj).val().split('_')[1] + "_" + $(obj).val().split('_')[0]);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="abc" type="text" onChange="Splitval(this)">
```