# split values are not getting calculated properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116922/split-values-in-jquery). I am adding line items with auto calculations according to the selection of price, quantity, discount and tax.

Only for tax I pass values as 1_2, i.e. both id and tax rate. So for the first line item I get a proper value for tax, but from the second onwards, whatever tax I select, it takes the first item's tax value. I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Here is my HTML through which I select the values:

```
    <td>
        <select name="tax[]" class="form-control tax" id="tax_1" style="width:80px;">
            <option value="">Tax</option>
<?php 
    $s1 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from taxes");
    while($s2 = mysqli_fetch_array($s1)) { 
        $options .= "<option value='". $s2['tax_id']."_".$s2['rate']."'>"
                    .$s2['name'].'-'.$s2['rate'] . "</option>"; 
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $s2['tax_id']."_".$s2['rate']; ?>">
                <?php echo $s2['name'].'-'.$s2['rate']; ?></option>
<?php
    }  
?>
        </select>
    </td>                        
</tr>
```

My script:

```
  $(".addmore").on('click', function() {
    count = $('table tr').length - 1;
    var data = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='productname_" + i + "' name='productname[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='productcode_" + i + "' name='productcode[]'/></td> <td><textarea class='form-control' id='description_"+ i + "' name='description[]'></textarea></td><td><select class='form-control uom' id='uom_" + i + "' name='uom[]'><option value=''>UOM</option>" + options1 + "</select></td><td><input class='form-control price' type='text' id='price_" + i + "' name='price[]'/></td><td><select class='form-control tax' id='tax_" + i + "' name='tax[]'><option value=''>Tax</option>" + options + "</select></select></td><td><input class='form-control quantity' type='text' id='quantity_" + i + "' name='quantity[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control discount' type='text' id='discount_" + i + "' name='discount[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control amount' type='text' id='amount_" + i + "' name='amount[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control tamount' type='text' id='tamount_" + i + "' name='tamount[]'/></td></tr>";
    $('table').append(data);
    row = i;
    $('#productname_' + i).autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax.php',
          dataType: "json",
          method: 'post',
          data: {
            name_startsWith: request.term,
            type: 'items_table',
            row_num: row
          },
          success: function(data) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
              var code = item.split("|");
              return {
                label: code[0],
                value: code[0],
                data: item    
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },

  $('body').on('change', '.quantity,.price,.discount,.tax', function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var qty = tr.find('.quantity').val();
    var price = tr.find('.price').val();
    var taxVal= $('.tax').val();
    var tax_id=taxVal.split('_')[0];
    var rate=taxVal.split('_')[1];
  // Here from 2nd line item i am getting 1st line items value for tax. 
    var dis = tr.find('.discount').val();
    var amt = (qty * price) - (qty * price * dis) / 100;
    var tax1 = (amt * (rate / 100));

    tax1 = Number((tax1).toFixed(2));
    tr.find('.tamount').val(tax1);
    ttotal();
    tr.find('.amount').val(amt);
    total();
    //tr.find('.ttotal1').val();
  });
```

Comment: Please post just the portion of the code that is not working properly.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: have edited my code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5vzx2g86/

Comment: One Question: Where is the closing of this function `$(".addmore").on('click', function() {`. Is this function includes `$('body').on('change', '.quantity,.price,.discount,.tax', function() {` this function too??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see.
This is because you're selecting the .tax selector like so:

`var taxVal= $('.tax').val();`

You should use `$(this)` to grab it. Because the way you're doing it, it'll always grab the first one.

Please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtrm65ha/) for an example

In short:
`$('.tax');` will select any element with the `.tax` class within the `DOM`.
When you use any type of binding, `this` will be the element that triggered the binding (The `change` event)

So, by grabbing `$(this)`, you'll be grabbing the element that has actually been changed. By grabbing `$('.tax')`, you'll just grab **any** `.tax` element that is in the `DOM`.

Hope this helps :)

### Example html

```
<select class="tax" id="tax">
  <option value="1_2">1_2</option>
  <option value="1_3">1_3</option>
  <option value="2_2">2_2</option>
</select>

<select class="tax" id="tax">
  <option value="3_2">3_2</option>
  <option value="3_3">3_3</option>
  <option value="3_2">3_2</option>
</select>
```

### Example jQuery

```
$('.tax').on('change', function() {

  var $changedInput = $(this);
  var value = $changedInput.val();
  var aValues = value.split('_');
  var tax_id = aValues[0];
  var rate = aValues[1];

  alert("tax_id: " + tax_id + " Rate:" + rate );
});
```

p.s. in your own code, you are already grabbing the parentrow for the other fields in order to find them, so why not do this for `.tax` also?

`tr.find('.tax').val();`

Comment: Thanks, but i put these line right after `$('body').on('change', '.quantity,.price,.discount,.tax', function() {`, no result. I do not understand where i am doing wrong

Comment: Thank you very much. I used `tr.find('.tax').val();`, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

> "So for the first line item I get a proper value for tax, but from the
>   second onwards, whatever tax I select, it takes the first item's tax
>   value."

As Far I See, You are not taking the current object values. You always referring the class name. Since, every inputs having ID ( separated by _ ). You can fetch the ID of that particular Input field and can split to get exact/current ID of it. Using this current ID, you can find other input values too.

**Updated Code**

```
$('body').on('change', '.quantity,.price,.discount,.tax', function() {

    var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    var id_clicked =  $(this).attr('id');
    var current_id = id_clicked.split("_")[1];

    var qty = tr.find("#quantity_"+current_id).val();
    var dis = tr.find("#tax_"+current_id).val();
    var price = tr.find("#price_"+current_id).val();
    var taxVal= tr.find("#tax"+current_id).val();
    var rate = taxVal.split('_')[1];

    var amt = (qty * price) - (qty * price * dis) / 100;
    var tax1 = (amt * (rate / 100));
    tax1 = Number((tax1).toFixed(2));

    tr.find('#tamount_'+current_id).val(tax1);
    tr.find('#tamount_'+current_id).val(amt);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Nana Partykar: I got that.